# How to center buttons in navigation bar?

Tags: css

[image]

What should I do to align the first 3 buttons in the center of the bar?

```
#navbar{
    list-style-type: none;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #212121;
}
```

Comment: provide a fiddle of whatever you have?

Comment: What you could do, is place the left buttons in a div and then simple add `margin: 0 auto;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your navigation bar you can put these three in one separate div and then align it to center

Answer (score 0):

Hello friends to center a that your
menu options (nav) you only need
to use the text-aling rule: center;
,why ? Because the menu list are
formed by '' li '' or '' ul '' and we
only apply this rule to list and
ready :), greetings from mexico;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0px;
        }
        .navbar{
            height: 60px;
            background-color: #bbb;
            line-height: 60px; //this will center inline elements in your navbar
        }
        .container{
            margin-left: 5%;
            margin-right: 5%;
        }
        .btn{
            background-color: white;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            width: 100px;
            border: none;
            border-radius: 2px;
            display: inline;
        }
        .nav{
            display: inline;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        .nav li{
            display: inline;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><button class="btn">Button1</button></li>
                <li><button class="btn">Button2</button></li>
                <li><a class="btn">&lt;a&gt; Button</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

The above code should work for you. I have shown buttons using anchor tag and also button tag